# Unable to install uwsgi in Pycharms

Tags: python, linux, pycharm, uwsgi

I am still unable to install uwsgi in Pycharms using Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS. I have tried running sudo apt-get install python-dev but I am still facing the same error. Any advices?

Executed command:
pip install uwsgi

ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:

Make sure that you have installed Python development packages for your operating system.

Command output:

Collecting uwsgi
Downloading uWSGI-2.0.19.1.tar.gz (803 kB)
Using legacy 'setup.py install' for uwsgi, since package 'wheel' is not installed.
Installing collected packages: uwsgi
Running setup.py install for uwsgi: started
Running setup.py install for uwsgi: finished with status 'error'

```
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
 command: /home/smbsg/Desktop/video_code/venv/bin/python -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/tmp/pip-install-t1spu51p/uwsgi_cdcb349c243845169232ef6f93e1ad7f/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/tmp/pip-install-t1spu51p/uwsgi_cdcb349c243845169232ef6f93e1ad7f/setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record /tmp/pip-record-s3ivcm9b/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers /home/smbsg/Desktop/video_code/venv/include/site/python3.9/uwsgi
     cwd: /tmp/pip-install-t1spu51p/uwsgi_cdcb349c243845169232ef6f93e1ad7f/
Complete output (110 lines):
/usr/lib/python3.9/distutils/dist.py:274: UserWarning: Unknown distribution option: 'descriptions'
  warnings.warn(msg)
running install
using profile: buildconf/default.ini
detected include path: ['/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/9/include', '/usr/local/include', '/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu', '/usr/include']
Patching "bin_name" to properly install_scripts dir
detected CPU cores: 8
configured CFLAGS: -O2 -I. -Wall -D_LARGEFILE_SOURCE -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 -Wextra -Wno-unused-parameter -Wno-missing-field-initializers -DUWSGI_HAS_IFADDRS -DUWSGI_LOCK_USE_MUTEX -DUWSGI_EVENT_USE_EPOLL -DUWSGI_EVENT_TIMER_USE_TIMERFD -DUWSGI_EVENT_FILEMONITOR_USE_INOTIFY -DUWSGI_VERSION="\"2.0.19.1\"" -DUWSGI_VERSION_BASE="2" -DUWSGI_VERSION_MAJOR="0" -DUWSGI_VERSION_MINOR="19" -DUWSGI_VERSION_REVISION="1" -DUWSGI_VERSION_CUSTOM="\"\"" -DUWSGI_YAML -DUWSGI_PLUGIN_DIR="\".\"" -DUWSGI_DECLARE_EMBEDDED_PLUGINS="UDEP(python);UDEP(gevent);UDEP(ping);UDEP(cache);UDEP(nagios);UDEP(rrdtool);UDEP(carbon);UDEP(rpc);UDEP(corerouter);UDEP(fastrouter);UDEP(http);UDEP(ugreen);UDEP(signal);UDEP(syslog);UDEP(rsyslog);UDEP(logsocket);UDEP(router_uwsgi);UDEP(router_redirect);UDEP(router_basicauth);UDEP(zergpool);UDEP(redislog);UDEP(mongodblog);UDEP(router_rewrite);UDEP(router_http);UDEP(logfile);UDEP(router_cache);UDEP(rawrouter);UDEP(router_static);UDEP(sslrouter);UDEP(spooler);UDEP(cheaper_busyness);UDEP(symcall);UDEP(transformation_tofile);UDEP(transformation_gzip);UDEP(transformation_chunked);UDEP(transformation_offload);UDEP(router_memcached);UDEP(router_redis);UDEP(router_hash);UDEP(router_expires);UDEP(router_metrics);UDEP(transformation_template);UDEP(stats_pusher_socket);" -DUWSGI_LOAD_EMBEDDED_PLUGINS="ULEP(python);ULEP(gevent);ULEP(ping);ULEP(cache);ULEP(nagios);ULEP(rrdtool);ULEP(carbon);ULEP(rpc);ULEP(corerouter);ULEP(fastrouter);ULEP(http);ULEP(ugreen);ULEP(signal);ULEP(syslog);ULEP(rsyslog);ULEP(logsocket);ULEP(router_uwsgi);ULEP(router_redirect);ULEP(router_basicauth);ULEP(zergpool);ULEP(redislog);ULEP(mongodblog);ULEP(router_rewrite);ULEP(router_http);ULEP(logfile);ULEP(router_cache);ULEP(rawrouter);ULEP(router_static);ULEP(sslrouter);ULEP(spooler);ULEP(cheaper_busyness);ULEP(symcall);ULEP(transformation_tofile);ULEP(transformation_gzip);ULEP(transformation_chunked);ULEP(transformation_offload);ULEP(router_memcached);ULEP(router_redis);ULEP(router_hash);ULEP(router_expires);ULEP(router_metrics);ULEP(transformation_template);ULEP(stats_pusher_socket);"
*** uWSGI compiling server core ***
[thread 1][x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc -pthread] core/utils.o
[thread 4][x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc -pthread] core/protocol.o
[thread 3][x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc -pthread] core/socket.o
[thread 0][x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc -pthread] core/logging.o
[thread 5][x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc -pthread] core/master.o
[thread 6][x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc -pthread] core/master_utils.o
[thread 7][x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc -pthread] core/emperor.o
[thread 2][x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc -pthread] core/notify.o
[thread 2][x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc -pthread] core/mule.o
[thread 4][x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc -pthread] core/subscription.o
[thread 2][x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc -pthread] core/stats.o
[thread 5][x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc -pthread] core/sendfile.o
[thread 0][x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc -pthread] core/async.o
[thread 6][x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc -pthread] core/master_checks.o
[thread 5][x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc -pthread] core/fifo.o
[thread 3][x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc -pthread] core/offload.o
[thread 4][x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc -pthread] core/io.o
[thread 2][x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc -pthread] core/static.o
[thread 7][x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc -pthread] core/websockets.o
[thread 5][x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc -pthread] core/spooler.o
[thread 0][x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc -pthread] core/snmp.o
[thread 6][x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc -pthread] core/exceptions.o
[thread 3][x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc -pthread] core/config.o
[thread 0][x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc -pthread] core/setup_utils.o
[thread 7][x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc -pthread] core/clock.o
[thread 2][x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc -pthread] core/init.o
[thread 5][x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc -pthread] core/buffer.o
[thread 7][x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc -pthread] core/reader.o
[thread 6][x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc -pthread] core/writer.o
[thread 0][x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc -pthread] core/alarm.o
[thread 1][x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc -pthread] core/cron.o
[thread 2][x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc -pthread] core/hooks.o
[thread 4][x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc -pthread] core/plugins.o
[thread 3][x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc -pthread] core/lock.o
[thread 5][x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc -pthread] core/cache.o
[thread 1][x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc -pthread] core/daemons.o
[thread 0][x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc -pthread] core/errors.o
[thread 7][x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc -pthread] core/hash.o
[thread 4][x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc -pthread] core/master_events.o
[thread 6][x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc -pthread] core/chunked.o
[thread 0][x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc -pthread] core/queue.o
[thread 2][x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc -pthread] core/event.o
[thread 3][x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc -pthread] core/signal.o
[thread 7][x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc -pthread] core/strings.o
[thread 1][x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc -pthread] core/progress.o
[thread 6][x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc -pthread] core/timebomb.o
[thread 4][x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc -pthread] core/ini.o
[thread 0][x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc -pthread] core/fsmon.o
[thread 6][x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc -pthread] core/mount.o
[thread 2][x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc -pthread] core/metrics.o
[thread 1][x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc -pthread] core/plugins_builder.o
[thread 4][x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc -pthread] core/sharedarea.o
[thread 3][x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc -pthread] core/rpc.o
[thread 7][x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc -pthread] core/gateway.o
[thread 0][x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc -pthread] core/loop.o
[thread 6][x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc -pthread] core/cookie.o
[thread 1][x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc -pthread] core/querystring.o
[thread 3][x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc -pthread] core/rb_timers.o
[thread 7][x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc -pthread] core/transformations.o
[thread 0][x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc -pthread] core/uwsgi.o
[thread 6][x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc -pthread] proto/base.o
[thread 1][x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc -pthread] proto/uwsgi.o
[thread 5][x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc -pthread] proto/http.o
[thread 4][x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc -pthread] proto/fastcgi.o
[thread 7][x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc -pthread] proto/scgi.o
[thread 1][x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc -pthread] proto/puwsgi.o
[thread 3][x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc -pthread] lib/linux_ns.o
[thread 6][x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc -pthread] core/yaml.o
[thread 4][x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc -pthread] core/dot_h.o
[thread 2][x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc -pthread] core/config_py.o
*** uWSGI compiling embedded plugins ***
[thread 4][x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc -pthread] plugins/python/python_plugin.o
[thread 2][x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc -pthread] plugins/python/pyutils.o
[thread 7][x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc -pthread] plugins/python/pyloader.o
[thread 1][x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc -pthread] plugins/python/wsgi_handlers.o
In file included from plugins/python/python_plugin.c:1:
plugins/python/uwsgi_python.h:2:10: fatal error: Python.h: No such file or directory
    2 | #include <Python.h>
      |          ^~~~~~~~~~
[thread 6][x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc -pthread] plugins/python/wsgi_headers.o
compilation terminated.
In file included from plugins/python/pyutils.c:1:
plugins/python/uwsgi_python.h:2:10: fatal error: Python.h: No such file or directory
    2 | #include <Python.h>
      |          ^~~~~~~~~~
compilation terminated.
In file included from plugins/python/pyloader.c:1:
plugins/python/uwsgi_python.h:2:10: fatal error: Python.h: No such file or directory
    2 | #include <Python.h>
      |          ^~~~~~~~~~
compilation terminated.
In file included from plugins/python/wsgi_handlers.c:1:
plugins/python/uwsgi_python.h:2:10: fatal error: Python.h: No such file or directory
    2 | #include <Python.h>
      |          ^~~~~~~~~~
compilation terminated.
In file included from plugins/python/wsgi_headers.c:1:
plugins/python/uwsgi_python.h:2:10: fatal error: Python.h: No such file or directory
    2 | #include <Python.h>
      |          ^~~~~~~~~~
compilation terminated.
----------------------------------------
```

ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: /home/smbsg/Desktop/video_code/venv/bin/python -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/tmp/pip-install-t1spu51p/uwsgi_cdcb349c243845169232ef6f93e1ad7f/setup.py'"'"'; **file**='"'"'/tmp/pip-install-t1spu51p/uwsgi_cdcb349c243845169232ef6f93e1ad7f/setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(**file**);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, **file**, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record /tmp/pip-record-s3ivcm9b/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers /home/smbsg/Desktop/video_code/venv/include/site/python3.9/uwsgi Check the logs for full command output.

---

After doing sudo apt install python3-dev,I still getting error.I am currently using python 3.9

Collecting uwsgi
Using cached uWSGI-2.0.19.1.tar.gz (803 kB)
Using legacy 'setup.py install' for uwsgi, since package 'wheel' is not installed.
Installing collected packages: uwsgi
Running setup.py install for uwsgi: started
Running setup.py install for uwsgi: finished with status 'error'

```
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
 command: /home/smbsg/Desktop/video_code/venv/bin/python -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/tmp/pip-install-715t_4on/uwsgi_3c73c57060e54997a0cdbaa63106f808/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/tmp/pip-install-715t_4on/uwsgi_3c73c57060e54997a0cdbaa63106f808/setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record /tmp/pip-record-6wg1lh5h/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers /home/smbsg/Desktop/video_code/venv/include/site/python3.9/uwsgi
     cwd: /tmp/pip-install-715t_4on/uwsgi_3c73c57060e54997a0cdbaa63106f808/
Complete output (112 lines):
/usr/lib/python3.9/distutils/dist.py:274: UserWarning: Unknown distribution option: 'descriptions'
  warnings.warn(msg)
running install
using profile: buildconf/default.ini
detected include path: ['/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/9/include', '/usr/local/include', '/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu', '/usr/include']
Patching "bin_name" to properly install_scripts dir
detected CPU cores: 8
configured CFLAGS: -O2 -I. -Wall -D_LARGEFILE_SOURCE -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 -Wextra -Wno-unused-parameter -Wno-missing-field-initializers -DUWSGI_HAS_IFADDRS -DUWSGI_ZLIB -DUWSGI_LOCK_USE_MUTEX -DUWSGI_EVENT_USE_EPOLL -DUWSGI_EVENT_TIMER_USE_TIMERFD -DUWSGI_EVENT_FILEMONITOR_USE_INOTIFY -DUWSGI_VERSION="\"2.0.19.1\"" -DUWSGI_VERSION_BASE="2" -DUWSGI_VERSION_MAJOR="0" -DUWSGI_VERSION_MINOR="19" -DUWSGI_VERSION_REVISION="1" -DUWSGI_VERSION_CUSTOM="\"\"" -DUWSGI_YAML -DUWSGI_XML -DUWSGI_XML_EXPAT -DUWSGI_PLUGIN_DIR="\".\"" -DUWSGI_DECLARE_EMBEDDED_PLUGINS="UDEP(python);UDEP(gevent);UDEP(ping);UDEP(cache);UDEP(nagios);UDEP(rrdtool);UDEP(carbon);UDEP(rpc);UDEP(corerouter);UDEP(fastrouter);UDEP(http);UDEP(ugreen);UDEP(signal);UDEP(syslog);UDEP(rsyslog);UDEP(logsocket);UDEP(router_uwsgi);UDEP(router_redirect);UDEP(router_basicauth);UDEP(zergpool);UDEP(redislog);UDEP(mongodblog);UDEP(router_rewrite);UDEP(router_http);UDEP(logfile);UDEP(router_cache);UDEP(rawrouter);UDEP(router_static);UDEP(sslrouter);UDEP(spooler);UDEP(cheaper_busyness);UDEP(symcall);UDEP(transformation_tofile);UDEP(transformation_gzip);UDEP(transformation_chunked);UDEP(transformation_offload);UDEP(router_memcached);UDEP(router_redis);UDEP(router_hash);UDEP(router_expires);UDEP(router_metrics);UDEP(transformation_template);UDEP(stats_pusher_socket);" -DUWSGI_LOAD_EMBEDDED_PLUGINS="ULEP(python);ULEP(gevent);ULEP(ping);ULEP(cache);ULEP(nagios);ULEP(rrdtool);ULEP(carbon);ULEP(rpc);ULEP(corerouter);ULEP(fastrouter);ULEP(http);ULEP(ugreen);ULEP(signal);ULEP(syslog);ULEP(rsyslog);ULEP(logsocket);ULEP(router_uwsgi);ULEP(router_redirect);ULEP(router_basicauth);ULEP(zergpool);ULEP(redislog);ULEP(mongodblog);ULEP(router_rewrite);ULEP(router_http);ULEP(logfile);ULEP(router_cache);ULEP(rawrouter);ULEP(router_static);ULEP(sslrouter);ULEP(spooler);ULEP(cheaper_busyness);ULEP(symcall);ULEP(transformation_tofile);ULEP(transformation_gzip);ULEP(transformation_chunked);ULEP(transformation_offload);ULEP(router_memcached);ULEP(router_redis);ULEP(router_hash);ULEP(router_expires);ULEP(router_metrics);ULEP(transformation_template);ULEP(stats_pusher_socket);"
*** uWSGI compiling server core ***
[thread 2][x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc -pthread] core/utils.o
[thread 3][x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc -pthread] core/protocol.o
[thread 4][x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc -pthread] core/socket.o
[thread 1][x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc -pthread] core/logging.o
[thread 5][x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc -pthread] core/master.o
[thread 6][x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc -pthread] core/master_utils.o
[thread 7][x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc -pthread] core/emperor.o
[thread 0][x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc -pthread] core/notify.o
[thread 0][x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc -pthread] core/mule.o
[thread 3][x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc -pthread] core/subscription.o
[thread 0][x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc -pthread] core/stats.o
[thread 5][x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc -pthread] core/sendfile.o
[thread 1][x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc -pthread] core/async.o
[thread 6][x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc -pthread] core/master_checks.o
[thread 5][x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc -pthread] core/fifo.o
[thread 4][x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc -pthread] core/offload.o
[thread 7][x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc -pthread] core/io.o
[thread 0][x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc -pthread] core/static.o
[thread 5][x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc -pthread] core/websockets.o
[thread 1][x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc -pthread] core/spooler.o
[thread 3][x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc -pthread] core/snmp.o
[thread 6][x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc -pthread] core/exceptions.o
[thread 4][x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc -pthread] core/config.o
[thread 3][x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc -pthread] core/setup_utils.o
[thread 5][x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc -pthread] core/clock.o
[thread 0][x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc -pthread] core/init.o
[thread 1][x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc -pthread] core/buffer.o
[thread 6][x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc -pthread] core/reader.o
[thread 5][x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc -pthread] core/writer.o
[thread 2][x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc -pthread] core/alarm.o
[thread 3][x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc -pthread] core/cron.o
[thread 7][x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc -pthread] core/hooks.o
[thread 0][x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc -pthread] core/plugins.o
[thread 4][x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc -pthread] core/lock.o
[thread 1][x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc -pthread] core/cache.o
[thread 3][x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc -pthread] core/daemons.o
[thread 2][x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc -pthread] core/errors.o
[thread 6][x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc -pthread] core/hash.o
[thread 0][x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc -pthread] core/master_events.o
[thread 5][x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc -pthread] core/chunked.o
[thread 7][x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc -pthread] core/queue.o
[thread 4][x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc -pthread] core/event.o
[thread 2][x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc -pthread] core/signal.o
[thread 6][x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc -pthread] core/strings.o
[thread 3][x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc -pthread] core/progress.o
[thread 0][x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc -pthread] core/timebomb.o
[thread 7][x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc -pthread] core/ini.o
[thread 5][x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc -pthread] core/fsmon.o
[thread 0][x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc -pthread] core/mount.o
[thread 4][x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc -pthread] core/metrics.o
[thread 3][x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc -pthread] core/plugins_builder.o
[thread 2][x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc -pthread] core/sharedarea.o
[thread 7][x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc -pthread] core/rpc.o
[thread 5][x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc -pthread] core/gateway.o
[thread 6][x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc -pthread] core/loop.o
[thread 3][x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc -pthread] core/cookie.o
[thread 0][x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc -pthread] core/querystring.o
[thread 6][x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc -pthread] core/rb_timers.o
[thread 7][x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc -pthread] core/transformations.o
[thread 5][x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc -pthread] core/uwsgi.o
[thread 3][x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc -pthread] proto/base.o
[thread 0][x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc -pthread] proto/uwsgi.o
[thread 1][x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc -pthread] proto/http.o
[thread 2][x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc -pthread] proto/fastcgi.o
[thread 7][x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc -pthread] proto/scgi.o
[thread 6][x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc -pthread] proto/puwsgi.o
[thread 0][x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc -pthread] lib/linux_ns.o
[thread 3][x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc -pthread] core/zlib.o
[thread 4][x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc -pthread] core/yaml.o
[thread 7][x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc -pthread] core/xmlconf.o
[thread 2][x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc -pthread] core/dot_h.o
[thread 6][x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc -pthread] core/config_py.o
*** uWSGI compiling embedded plugins ***
[thread 6][x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc -pthread] plugins/python/python_plugin.o
[thread 2][x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc -pthread] plugins/python/pyutils.o
[thread 0][x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc -pthread] plugins/python/pyloader.o
[thread 3][x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc -pthread] plugins/python/wsgi_handlers.o
[thread 4][x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc -pthread] plugins/python/wsgi_headers.o
In file included from plugins/python/pyutils.c:1:
plugins/python/uwsgi_python.h:2:10: fatal error: Python.h: No such file or directory
    2 | #include <Python.h>
      |          ^~~~~~~~~~
In file included from plugins/python/python_plugin.c:1:
plugins/python/uwsgi_python.h:2:10: fatal error: Python.h: No such file or directory
    2 | #include <Python.h>
      |          ^~~~~~~~~~
compilation terminated.
compilation terminated.
In file included from plugins/python/pyloader.c:1:
plugins/python/uwsgi_python.h:2:10: fatal error: Python.h: No such file or directory
    2 | #include <Python.h>
      |          ^~~~~~~~~~
compilation terminated.
In file included from plugins/python/wsgi_handlers.c:1:
plugins/python/uwsgi_python.h:2:10: fatal error: Python.h: No such file or directory
    2 | #include <Python.h>
      |          ^~~~~~~~~~
compilation terminated.
In file included from plugins/python/wsgi_headers.c:1:
plugins/python/uwsgi_python.h:2:10: fatal error: Python.h: No such file or directory
    2 | #include <Python.h>
      |          ^~~~~~~~~~
compilation terminated.
----------------------------------------
```

ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: /home/smbsg/Desktop/video_code/venv/bin/python -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/tmp/pip-install-715t_4on/uwsgi_3c73c57060e54997a0cdbaa63106f808/setup.py'"'"'; **file**='"'"'/tmp/pip-install-715t_4on/uwsgi_3c73c57060e54997a0cdbaa63106f808/setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(**file**);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, **file**, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record /tmp/pip-record-6wg1lh5h/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers /home/smbsg/Desktop/video_code/venv/include/site/python3.9/uwsgi Check the logs for full command output.

Answer (score 2):

You need to install Python development files, which includes `Python.h`

```
sudo apt install python3-dev
```

Comment: To be more specific `python3.9-dev`